# How to change VMWare Workstation 12 network address to avoid Wifi network collision

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

how do I force Vmware Workstation 12 to use a different network address instead of default 192.168.88.0?

I usually connect to a WiFi network that I have no control over and it collides with the Vmware's network. I can change the IP address on the guest OS as well as its virtual NIC on the host but I end up not being able to connect to the guest OS at all. Currently I'm forced to disable the adapter which means I can't connect to the VM.

**EDIT**: Added screenshot

[image]

Comment: Go into your virtual network editor, click change settings, select the network with the issue, you should be able to see the subnets on the right column.  After you've selected the network, change the subnet ID on the bottom of the window to something other than .88.

Comment: @essjae Virtual Network Editor is no longer available in WS 12. Any other method?

Comment: I don't use Player, only the Pro version.  You could try selecting a different VMnet from the "custom: specific virtual network" section.  IIRC, they are each different.